# Sorting characters inside a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Given a string `s`, two numbers `n` and `m`, I have to sort the characters of the string between the two indeces (both included) in descending order.

I wrote this program, but I am not getting the correct sorted string.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t ;
    cin >>t ;
    while(t--) {
        int n ,m ,i ,j;
        string s ;
        char c ;
        cin >> s >> n >> m ;
        for(i=n;i<m;i++) {
            for(j=n+1;j<=m;j++) {
                if( s[j]>s[i] ) {
                    swap(s[i],s[j]) ;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << s  << '\n' ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please include an example input/output

Comment: first of all, your string is default constructed and doesn't contain anything ;)

Comment: Try a debugger for a small example.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `s[j] > s[i]` - and swapping if it does, even if `i < j`.

To solve this, you probably want to start the second loop from `i+1` instead of from `n+1`.

```
for(i=n;i<m;i++){
  for(j=i+1;j<=m;j++){
  //    ^ i instead of n
    if( s[j]>s[i] ) {
      swap(s[i],s[j]) ;
    }
  }
}
```

As a side note, this is pretty inefficient sorting algorithm.

P.S. make sure `j<=m` is intended and you don't need strong inequality.

Comment: no raw loops please ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use the standard library utilities in this case, for example

```
auto mid = s.substr(n, m-n);
std::sort(mid.begin(), mid.end(), std::greater<char>());
std::cout << s.substr(0, n) << mid << s.substr(m, s.size()-m);
```

So for example

```
s = "dictionary"
n = 2
m = 8
```

would produce

```
ditonicary
```

Comment: That beats the intended purpose of the (what seems to be an assignment) of learning to sort though.

Comment: @amit: so does trying to use SO as a debugger replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second the answer given by @CoryCramer, but I'd do it in place:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main( void )
{
    std::string s = "This is the string to sort";

    size_t m = 3;
    size_t n = 10;
    std::sort( s.begin() + m, s.begin() + n );
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Output: Thi  hisste string to sort

Try not to use raw loops if there is no reason, IMHO my code is a lot more readable than what OP suggested.